# How to have logging in Vue.js without console.log?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, logging, vuex

I want to have console logging while I'm developing in Vue.js but want it disabled for production.

There is a module `vuejs-logger` that works fine inside of a Vue component and will be disabled in production mode. But it will not work (for instance) in my service files or library files (outside of the Vue instance) nor in Vuex.

Does anyone have any other suggestions? Vue.js integrated or otherwise?

Stay safe, TIA

**Edit:** Just to clarify, `vuejs-logger`'s Typescript integration is the real problem. It throws up so many TS errors that I cannot use it. The actual JS logging seems to work... I'm still interested in other solutions that may work smoothly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider building your own simple wrapper which will work everywhere, **assuming you are using Webpack**, like the following:

```
declare const NODE_ENV: any;

export function log(message: String, level?: 'info' | 'warn' | 'error') {

    // WHEN RUNNING WEBPACK WITH `PRODUCTION` build,
    // IT WILL REMOVE THE FOLLOWING CODE.

    if (NODE_ENV !== 'production') {

        if (level === 'error') {
            console.error(message);
        } else if (level === 'warn') {
            console.warn(message);
        } else {
            console.log(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Being a simple function, you can literally import this anywhere in your code including component files or other non-component files. The important point here is to note the use of the `NODE_ENV` variable which will be injected by Webpack when running in Production mode. Similar setups exist for Rollup and other bundlers. Read more about this [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#specify-the-mode). When Webpack is bundling the code with **production mode**, it will ignore the code inside `if (NODE_ENV !== 'production') { /* some code */ }` construct.

Also, if you need to wrap it inside a plugin so that it is available on every component instance using the `this` pointer then:

```
const MyLogger = {
    install(Vue: Vue, options: any) {

        // Add an instance method
        Vue.prototype.log = log;
    }
};

Vue.install(MyLogger);
```

Of course, if you are using TypeScript, then you must teach TypeScript using module augmentation like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        log(message: string, level?: 'info' | 'warn' | 'error'): void;
    }
}
```

The above snippet should be present inside your `typings` folder like specified using `tsconfig.json`. The directory path would be: `ROOT/typings/vue/index.d.ts`.

In `tsconfig.json` file, `typings` array should be set to:

```
"typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "./typings"
],
```

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer. I'll give both ideas a try later today. Great!

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to use the `vuejs3-logger` in modules that are not components. These are the required steps:

1. create a module `logger.js` with content

```
import VueLogger from 'vuejs3-logger'
import { createApp } from 'vue'

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const vlOptions = {
    isEnabled: true,
    logLevel : isProduction ? 'info' : 'debug',
    stringifyArguments : false,
    showLogLevel : true,
    showMethodName : true,
    separator: '|',
    showConsoleColors: true
};

// create a dummy app that can be used as logger in other js modules
const app = createApp({})
app.use(VueLogger, vlOptions);
const logger = app.config.globalProperties.$log;

export {VueLogger, vlOptions, logger};
```

2. use this to create your Vue app as usual

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import {VueLogger, vlOptions} from './logger.js'
import App from '../components/App.vue'

createApp(App)
  .use(VueLogger, vlOptions)
  .mount('#app');
```

3. In your external JavaScript module, do this:

```
import {logger} from './logger.js'

logger.debug("Hi there!")
```

The point is that when you change the logging level in `logger.js`, all your JavaScript modules will adapt to this logging level as well.

Comment: This logger is not accessible outside of the component. like in store files. I am using typescript. pania store.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer this solution works in JavaScript modules outside components, e.g. it works in pinia store files.